# Name 'driver' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm writing a bot to access instagram, but it is giving me an error that I cannot identify.I am a beginner and I am having trouble finding the error. I am open to new friendships and to share knowledge. Thanks guys!!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import random

class InstagramBot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"C:\Users\bruno\Desktop\geckodriver-v0.29.1-win64\geckodriver.exe")
           
    def login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=pt-br")
   
    campo_usuario = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
    campo_usuario.click()
    campo_usuario.clear()
    campo_usuario.send_keys(self.username)
    campo_senha = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
    campo_senha.click()
    campo_senha.clear()
    campo_senha.send_keys(self.password)
    campo_senha.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
 
   
brunoBot = InstagramBot("user","senha1234")  
brunoBot.login()
```

error:

```
 File "c:\Users\bruno\Desktop\geckodriver-v0.29.1-win64\igBot.py", line 16, in InstagramBot
    campo_usuario = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
NameError: name 'driver' is not defined
PS C:\Users\bruno\Desktop\geckodriver-v0.29.1-win64>
```

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/wronglanguage

Comment: You can post in [pt.so]

Comment: You need to fix the indentation of the `login()` function. All the lines beginning with `campo_usuario` need to be indented.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is an English-only site.

Answer (score 0):

You have to respect the identation for the `login` method:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import random

class InstagramBot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"C:\Users\bruno\Desktop\geckodriver-v0.29.1-win64\geckodriver.exe")
           
    def login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=pt-br")
   
        campo_usuario = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
        campo_usuario.click()
        campo_usuario.clear()
        campo_usuario.send_keys(self.username)
        campo_senha = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
        campo_senha.click()
        campo_senha.clear()
        campo_senha.send_keys(self.password)
        campo_senha.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
 
   
brunoBot = InstagramBot("user","senha1234")  
brunoBot.login()
```